# C# wpf xaml datagrid binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, binding

I want the following datagrid:

```
Name questionpar1  | Name QuestionPar2  | Name QuestionPar3  | ...
string qp1 of var1 | string qp2 of var1 | string qp3 of var1 | ...
string qp1 of var2 | string qp2 of var2 | string qp3 of var2 | ...
...
```

these are my classes:

Question with property `IEnumerable<Variation> Variations`

Variation with property `IEnumerable<<keyValuePair<QuestionParameter,string>>> QuestionParameters`

QuestionParameter has the property Name which is a string

Can Someone show me the code to make this datagrid?? I use MVVM so you can use: `{Binding Path=}`

thanks

Comment: ok then what have you got so far and were are is the question?

Comment: Well, I have not really an idea how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, not sure though:

```
var dataGrid = dataGridQuestions;

int i = 1;
foreach (var parameter in QuestionParameters)
{
    var binding = new Binding("qp" + (i++).ToString());
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    var column = DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = binding, Header=parameter.Value };
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: In XAML you can do static things rather well. For trickery like this I would recommend to use codebehind. Just because it's more compact. There's nothing wrong with that.